# How to know if line intersects with a circle on google map using Lat,Long

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

How to know if line intersects with a circle on google map using location points

Comment: This seems to be a geometric problem: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

Comment: I need solution in javascript!

Comment: JavaScript includes math library functions that should allow you to apply the techniques described in the linked article to solve your problem. A more practical explanation than WolframAlpha's might be found on [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note however, that the linked wolfram alpha article doesn't specify the coördinate system that's being used (cartesian is a reasonable assumption), whereas the OP specified that their coörds are in lat/lon format. Lat/lon isn't the same thing as cartesian (different projections) so the results from applying those techniques alone may give skewed results...

Comment: If there are no other questions about solving this problem specifically for lat/lon, I would probably start by looking for questions/solutions for this problem when using _polar coördinates_, since lat/lon is very similar to those (the main difference is that WGS84, the common projection model in use, doesn't specify a perfect sphere because the earth isn't).